# run rake ts:index from within a rake task

Tags: command, rake, system, task, sphinx

I am running Rails 2.3.5.

In my project I have in lib/tasks the following rake task (test_task.rake):

```
desc 'test_synchro_task'
task :test_synchro_task => :environment do
    # A bunch of things that are properly executed (basically I am inserting 
    # in the database)...
    # ...
    # and once the above is done, I want the following to be executed,
    # the sphinx index to be rebuild, but it is NOT :
    system("cd /sites/project/app")
    system("RAILS_ENV='staging' rake ts:index")
end
```

I trigger the execution of the task via a crontab containing the following entry:

```
13 14 * * * cd /sites/project/app && /sites/ruby/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=staging test_task
```

which id correctly called and executed except for 2 system lines in the task.

Please note that when I place those 2 system lines in a ruby test.rb file in my project script directory, and run it manually using the ruby command:

```
ruby test.rb
```

those 2 system commands are properly executed and the index is rebuilt correctly.

In my rake task I tried replacing those 2 system lines by:

```
%x["cd /sites/project/app"]
%x["RAILS_ENV='staging' rake ts:index"]
```

or by

```
@cmd="cd /sites/project/app; RAILS_ENV='staging' rake ts:index"
`#{@cmd}`
```

but the rake ts:index is still not executed.

Any idea why?

Many thanks.

Yves

Comment: Just to clarify. There is a typo in my post. The description and task name are really OK, i.e. both: test_task and not test_synchro_task.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved:

1- In the ruby script, I found that the $?.exitstatus was 127, which is "command not found".

2- This hinted me to a PATH problem occurring in the context of cron.

3- Found that post: http://dewful.com/?p=157 titled "Ruby - Cron Not Working For Ruby Script".

4- Added the PATH in the crontab and everything works fine.

Yves